# Unknown provider error on btfModal

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Brian Ford's [angular-modal](https://github.com/btford/angular-modal) library to provide modals for my app. It works properly in development, but minification seems to break it even though I'm using ngmin through a gulp build process.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t <- btfModal <- deleteConfirmationModal
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17-build.225+sha.9227a5d/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%20%3C-%20t%20%3C-%20btfModal%20%3C-NaNeleteConfirmationModal
    at http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:697
    at http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:17123
    at Object.n [as get] (http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:16388)
    at http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:17218
    at n (http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:16388)
    at Object.r [as invoke] (http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:16673)
    at http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:17236
    at n (http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:16388)
    at Object.r [as invoke] (http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:16673)
    at http://localhost:3005/live/vendors.min.js:1:17236
```

Based on what I've read in general about `Unknown provider` errors, I'm sure it’s a problem with dependency injection. I've tried every permutation I can think of, but I can't make it work.

Here's the pertinent code:

Creates the module:

```
angular.module('gridsmartWebClient.modal', ['btford.modal']);
```

Factory:

```
angular.
    module('gridsmartWebClient.modal')
        .factory('deleteConfirmationModal', function (btfModal) {
            'use strict';
            return btfModal({
                controller: 'DeleteModalCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'modal',
                templateUrl: '/gridsmart-web-client/camera/delete-confirmation.html'
            });
        })
```

Factory after ngmin:

```
angular.module('gridsmartWebClient.modal').factory('deleteConfirmationModal', [
  'btfModal',
  function (btfModal) {
    'use strict';
    return btfModal({
      controller: 'DeleteModalCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'modal',
      templateUrl: '/gridsmart-web-client/camera/delete-confirmation.html'
    });
  }
])
```

App dependencies:

```
angular.module('gridsmartWebClient', [
  'ngRoute',
  'gridsmartWebClient.grid',
  'gridsmartWebClient.camera',
  'gridsmartWebClient.modal',
  'gridsmartWebClient.utils',
  'dropdownDirective',
  'btford.modal',
  'gridsmart-web-client-templates'
])
```

So, despite the fact I know there's a problem with dependency injections, I can't see what it would be. The module the factory is declared in has been injected in the app. I've looked through other responses to similar questions but answers are either very specific to the respective scenarios or general so as not to be especially useful to me. (e.g. "It's a dependency problem."). What gives?

Comment: The problem is in vendors.min.js, not your code. You need ngmin all your vendor scripts as well.

Comment: @YeLiu You're absolutely right. Submit this as an answer, and I'll mark it correct. Thank you!

Comment: That's great! I simply copied my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in vendors.min.js, not your code. You need ngmin all your vendor scripts as well.